# dimissModalViewControllerAnimated causing tableView to be full screen?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, uiviewcontroller

I have a RootViewController with 2 tableViews as subviews (created in IB) each with their own tableViewController class (handleing fetchRequests etc.)

1 tableView is static (no data changed by user or modelViews).

tableView 2 has a button in the header which presents an imagePickerController.
No issues so far.

Problem is, when i dismiss the imagePicker

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

TableView 2 becomes full screen i have tried

```
[[self rootViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Nothing happens at all. It sticks on the image picker.

I suspect this is due to there being very little of the view being created programmaticaly.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

DetartrateD

```
 -(IBAction)addImageTableAPressed {
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[imagePicker release];  
}

            RootViewController
             ||            ||
             ||            ||    
             \/            \/          addImageTableAPressed
  TableViewControlA  TableViewControlB --------------------->modelViewController
```

To resolve mananagedObjectContect.....

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad {...
 if(managedObjectContext == nil) 
{ 
    managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);
}
   ...
  }
```

Comment: How do you present the imagePickerController? Could you post some code?

Comment: Thanks. Which view controller implements the `addImageTableAPressed` method? If the target of `presentModalViewController:animated:` is not your RootViewController, then that might explain your problem. Also, I would advise against a situation where different view controllers manage parts or subviews of your root view...

Comment: @octy cheers, the addImageTableAPressed is implemented by TableViewControllerB (see above). I tried to avoid it but the only way I could get 2 tableViews in a single view and be able to have  data(fetch requests) for both. I was unable to create more then 1 fetch request in a single class. Also, having the rootViewCon as a ViewController I am able to have an imageView that was essential. I get that the parent viewCont would be tViewControllerB and this is popped back to the top of the stack when the imagePicker is resigned. I need somehow to make rootView the parent but keep the design as is..

Comment: Ok, in that case I'd say it's better if you define a UIView (the rootView) including 2 subviews (TableViewA and TableViewB). Your RootViewController's view will be rootView, and this controller will have to be the data source and delegate of both table views. I will write an answer detailing this approach, but first, why do you say you were 'not able to implement more than 1 fetch request in a single class'?

Comment: I mean, do you have any particular restriction to limit yourself to implementing 1 fetch request per single class?

Comment: Well it may be inexperience sigh..... I  use a fetch request with a sort descriptor to populate each tableView. They use a seperate sort descriptor to populate their respective cells. It seemed the most obvious way of doing things was to have 2 dedicated tableViewController classes to deal with this. I did have a headache (2 days) getting the managed object context passed to the tableViewControler class (went through everything, no MOM, MOC is nil, all where coming back as expected) it the end had to add a snippet of code ( above) to get me back in the game. Im intrigued at your suggestion..

Comment: @octy RESOLVED issue..... Thought outside the box a little. Binned the imagePicker nested in my tableView header and took advantage of the rootView. Added a custom UIButton with required IBAction and all works like a charm! Resigning the imagePicker takes me back to rootView (being its now parent view controller) and data reloads on my tableView as expected. Sometimes a good nights sleep does the trick.... Thank you so much for your contribution, its very much appriciated!! DetartrateD

Comment: No problem, glad you were able to make it work! For further reference, I will post an answer where a single view controller manages the 2 table views since I think it's the way to go. Take care!

Comment: @octy REALLY USEFUL INFO BUDDY!!! Thanks a lot for the effort and an invaluable lesson on the ability to perform multiple fetch requests in a single class. I got into the habit of single fetch requesting using        - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController   so was limiting myself on the ability to have 2 tableViews in a single class (I only ever needed to use 1 tableView in my previous app ). Code has now been tweaked using your tips and works like a treat. See you around!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in one of my comments, I would prefer having a single view controller managing the two table views. Define a UIView (the rootView) including 2 subviews (tableViewA and tableViewB). Your RootViewController's view will be rootView, and this controller will have to be the data source and delegate of both table views. The code I will give here is by no means complete nor optimal, but gives you a good idea of what is needed to implement my solution.

For example:

```
@interface RootViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSArray *dataArrayA;
    NSArray *dataArrayB;
    UITableView tableViewA;
    UITableView tableViewB;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *dataArrayA;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *dataArrayB;

// in IB, link the dataSource and delegate outlets of both tables to RootViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView tableViewA;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView tableViewB;

// this property will allow you to pass the MOC to the RootViewController from 
// the parent view controller, instead of accessing the app delegate from RootViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

// ... etc.

@end



@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize dataArrayA;
@synthesize dataArrayB;
@synthesize tableViewA;
@synthesize tableViewB;
@synthesize context;

// initialize dataArrayA and dataArrayB
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *error = nil;

    // initialize and configure your fetch request for data going into tableViewA
    NSFetchRequest fetchRequestA = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    // configure the entity, sort descriptors, predicate, etc.
    // ...

    // perform the fetch
    self.dataArrayA = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestA error:&error];

    // do the same for the data going into tableViewB - the code is very similar, you
    // could factor it out in a private method instead of duplicating it here
    // NSFetchRequest fetchRequestB = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 

    // omitting the details ... etc.

    self.dataArrayB = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestB error:&error];

    // release objects you don't need anymore, according to memory management rules
    [fetchRequestA release];
    [fetchRequestB release];
}


// Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // if you have a different number of sections in tableViewA and tableViewB
/*
    if (tableView == tableViewA) {
        return ??;
    } else {
        return ??
    }
*/

    // otherwise, if both table views contain one section
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in each table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == tableViewA) {
        return [dataArrayA count];
    } else {
        return [dataArrayB count];
    }
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if (tableView == tableViewA) {
        // get the data for the current row in tableViewA
        id objectA = [dataArrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // configure the cell for tableViewA
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierA];

        // etc...
    } else {
        // get the data for the current row in tableViewB
        id objectB = [dataArrayB objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // configure the cell for tableViewB
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierB];
        // etc...
    }
    return cell;
}

// And so on, the same idea applies for the other UITableViewDelegate you would need to 
// implement...


- (void)dealloc {
    [dataArrayA release];
    [dataArrayB release];
    [tableViewA release];
    [tableViewB release];
    [context release];

    // etc...

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I hope you'll find this useful.

Comment: REALLY USEFUL INFO BUDDY!!! Thanks a lot for the effort and an invaluable lesson on the ability to perform multiple fetch requests in a single class. I got into the habit of single fetch requesting using - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController so was limiting myself on the ability to have 2 tableViews in a single class (I only ever needed to use 1 tableView in my previous app's ). Code has now been tweaked using your tips and works like a treat. See you around!